# Mui v5 - TreeView - Scroll so recent expanded is on top

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, material-ui, treeview

The functionality I'm trying to achieve is that when I click on a `TreeItem` that has children and expand it, a scroll accures so that the expanded item is shown on top. How can I implement that?

Answer (score 1):

You can make some component in App.(j|t)sx and there make this function

```
useEffect(() => {
    sctollOnTop();
});
```

and that will rescroll on every rout change... if you don't need to run it on scroll change just make some other function and reuse that on each open of item.